# run time error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument on math

Tags: excel, vba

I get the error on gTempConvC = line. I think its the ^ but not sure what to replace it with since I can't see to find their use in Excel sheet. This formula was used in a sheet and now i'm converting it to vba

```vb
Function gTempConvC(thermistorCnt As Integer, refRCnt As Integer) As Single
Dim CoA As Single
Dim CoB As Single
Dim CoC As Single
Dim CoD As Single
Dim Rth As Single
Dim Kth As Single
    CoA = 0.0009180023
    CoB = 0.0001964561
    CoC = 0.0000007061775
    CoD = 0.00000005283566
    Kth = -273.15 'Constant Degrees Kelvin
        '=((A12*(71500+1000)/B12)-1000) where A12 is thermistorCnt & B12 refRCnt
        Rth = ((thermistorCnt * (71500 + 1000) / refRCnt) - 1000)
        '=(-273.15)+(CoA+CoB*LN(C12)+CoC*LN(C12)^2+CoD*LN(C12)^3)^-1
        gTempConvC = (Kth) + (CoA + CoB * Log(Kth) + CoC * Log(Kth) ^ 2 + CoD * Log(Kth) ^ 3) ^ -1
```

Comment: you can use the application.power() function if you feel the "^" isn't recognized, though it should be (i use it often).

Comment: You're error comes from taking the log of a negative number by calling `Log(Kth)`.

Comment: @Cyril indeed, `^` is the type hint character for `LongLong`, so for it to be parsed as such rather than as the "power" operator, it would have to be stitched to some literal, e.g. `42^` (no space). Now I'm confused about `Kth` being negative Kelvin degrees...

Comment: looks like he's doing 0 K, or -273.15 C @MathieuGuindon

Comment: What is your goal here, Rick?  Looks like you're inverting the Steinhart resistance to calculate a temperature, in which case you should be adding 273.15 at the end of your calculation, which uses termpature units in Kelvin

Comment: Maybe `Log(Kth)` should be `Log(Rth)`?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't like your negative 273.15 parameter.

Comment: in my opinion is better to use double if you handle numbers with decimals.